# How can we have an image over multiple blocks or a cell of text in XSL-FO? I have attached an image for the reference. I want this type of output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

[image: Cross over text]

I want the logic to be written in XSL-FO. Please suggest.

```
<fo:block-container position="absolute" top="10pt" left="10pt" height="15pt" width="100%">(1)
  <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic src="Image.gif" width="50mm" height="7.5mm" scaling="uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Comment: This is not the way SO works. Rather, you try and write the XSL-FO code yourself. If, in the course of writing the code, you encounter any problems, that's when you come back here and share your code.

Comment: @Mathias - I needed only a suggestion and not the full code. But still if code is required then you can see the above.

Comment: Thanks. Now, in what way does your approach not work as intended? Any error message you get, flaws in the resulting PDF...? Meanwhile, here is your suggestion: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect3/fofixedposn.html#d12186e70 .